# Запуск sh-скрипта с передачей в него данных из консоли

Tags: bash, консоль, sh

Запуск sh-скрипта с передачей в него данных из консоли.

Например что бы выглядело следующим образом:

```
$./myscript.sh "какая-то строка"
```

и передать `какая-то строка` внутрь скрипта.

Можно ли так сделать и что для этого гуглить?

Comment: Гуглите "параметры в баш-скрипте", хотя я загуглил уже: https://habr.com/company/ruvds/blog/326328/ - Вам осталось только прочитать...

Comment: @Dillingerèmorto, да это оно. Оформите как ответ как-нибудь - отмечу

Comment: Как-нибудь оформлю, потом, но только как "общий", если вы не против.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для того, чтобы прочитать в скрипте переданный аргумент используйте переменные (внутри скрипта) `$1..$9`
Кроме этого есть:
`$0` - это переменная содержащая имя скрипта.
`$$` - id процесса скрипта.

К примеру для того, чтобы вывести из скрипта строку, переданную ему в качестве аргумента можно сделать так:
`./my_script 'Hello'`

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "$1"
```

`# Hello`

`./my_script 'Hello' 'World'`

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "$1 $2"
```

`# Hello World`

Answer (score 1):

*Комментарии только с 50 репутации..*

Хочу дополнить ответ @Andrey:

```
$ cat ./t1.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo "${10}"

$ ./t1.sh "1q" "2w" "3e" "4r" "5t" "6y" "7u" "8i" "9o" "10a" "11s"
10a
```

Т.е. можно передавать больше 9 аргументов (хотя практически везде пишут, что только 9), проверено на:

```
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.4.12(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
```

Или по старинке использовать `shift`:

```
$ cat ./t1.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
shift
echo "$9"

$ ./t1.sh "1q" "2w" "3e" "4r" "5t" "6y" "7u" "8i" "9o" "10a" "11s"
10a
```